# How to pass extra kwargs to form in django modelformset factory?

Tags: django, django-forms

How can i pass extra kwargs to django modelform in modelformset factory

I want for example, disable all form fields in detail view.

forms.py:

```
class ConceptForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = app_models.Concept
    fields = '__all__'

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    self.action = kwargs.pop('action', None)

    super(ConceptForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    if self.action is not None:
      if self.action == 'detail':
        for field in self.fields:
          self.fields[field].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

views.py

```
modelformset = modelformset_factory(
  model = model,
  fields = show_fields,
  form = ConceptForm(kwargs={'action': 'detail'), <-- I would like something like this
)
```

The error is:

> 'ConceptForm' object is not callable

Without call init not errors showed but the form fields not are disabled

```
modelformset = modelformset_factory(
  model = model,
  fields = show_fields,
  form = ConceptForm
)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is specified in the [*Passing custom parameters to formset forms* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/#passing-custom-parameters-to-formset-forms), you can make use of the **`form_kwargs=…`** parameter of the `FormSet`:

```
ConceptFormSet = modelformset_factory(
    model = Concept,
    form = ConceptForm,
    fields = show_fields
)
formset = ConceptFormSet(form_kwargs={'action': 'detail'})
```