# Model.Form Queryset

Tags: django

I have a model.form which I need to apply a queryset to filter the choices available within a select field.

```
class AnswerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProjectQuestionnaireAnswer
        fields = ('answer','notes')

        widgets = {
            'answer': forms.Select(choices = Choice.objects.filter(question_id = 1),attrs={'class': 'form-control select2'}),
            'notes': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Add notes to question here'}),
        }
```

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(ProjectQuestionnaireQuestion, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.choice_text)
```

```
class ProjectQuestionnaireAnswer(models.Model):
    YN_Choices = [
        ('Yes', 'Yes'),
        ('No', 'No'),
        ('Unknown', 'Unknown')
    ]
    question = models.ForeignKey(ProjectQuestionnaireQuestion, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Choice, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
    response = models.ForeignKey(ProjectQuestionnaireResponse, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
                models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['question','response'], name='project_unique_response2'),
            ]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.answer)
```

```
def get_questionnaire(request, project_id, questionnaire_id):

    # Get or Create the Response object for the parameters
    next = request.POST.get('next', '/')
    response, created = ProjectQuestionnaireResponse.objects.get_or_create(
        project_name_id=project_id, questionnaire_id=questionnaire_id
    )

    AnswerFormSet = modelformset_factory(ProjectQuestionnaireAnswer, form=AnswerForm, fields=('answer','notes',), extra=0)

    answer_queryset = ProjectQuestionnaireAnswer.objects.filter(response=response
    ).order_by('question__sequence'
    ).select_related('question')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = AnswerFormSet(request.POST)
        instances = formset.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
    else:
        # Get the list of questions for which no Answer exists
        new_answers = ProjectQuestionnaireQuestion.objects.filter(
            questionnaire__projectquestionnaireresponse=response
        ).exclude(
            projectquestionnaireanswer__response=response
        )

        # This is safe to execute every time. If all answers exist, nothing happens
        for new_answer in new_answers:
            ProjectQuestionnaireAnswer(question=new_answer, response=response).save()

        answer_formset = AnswerFormSet(queryset=answer_queryset)
                

    return render(request, 'project_evaluation.html', {'formset': answer_formset,'project_name':response.project_name,'title':response.questionnaire.title})
```

I'm not sure how to write the query to only return the choices related to the question. I've tested with `choices = Choice.objects.filter(question_id = 1)` which does return me the choices for question 1, but need it for each question?

And then how do I present this in my template?

`{{ form.answer.choices }}` ??

Thanks

Comment: Share your `ProjectQuestionnaireAnswer` model.

Comment: Hi Willem. I've updated the post with the model. Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your problem with presenting it in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement it in the `__init__` method.

This is my suggestion:

```py
class AnswerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProjectQuestionnaireAnswer
        fields = ('answer','notes')

        widgets = {
            'notes': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Add notes to question here'}),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         question_id = kwargs.pop('question_id')
         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.fields['answer'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
             queryset=Choice.objects.filter(question_id=question_id),
             widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control select2'})
         )
```

Then when initializing the form, you need to pass to it the `question_id` argument. For the example in the post: `AnswerForm(question_id=1)`

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It throws this error:   File "D:\_AzDo\Python.WebApp\app\forms.py", line 81, in __init__
    question_id = kwargs.pop('question_id')
KeyError: 'question_id'
Which i think is because of `post: AnswerForm(question_id=1)` where do i put that in my view?

Comment: Added my view as im using model formset

Comment: There is the `form_kwargs` kwarg in the AnswerFormSet initializer. So `AnswerFormSet(request.POST, form_kwargs={'question_id': 1})`

Comment: See related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59827348/how-to-pass-extra-kwargs-to-form-in-django-modelformset-factory

Comment: Thanks, vinkomlacic. I'm still getting the same error. :( Ill take a look at the link

Comment: Have you used the kwarg in both places? Both where you have `request.POST` and where you don't?

Comment: I've added `AnswerFormSet(request.POST, form_kwargs={'question_id': 1})` and added the `def __init__`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243097/discussion-between-vinkomlacic-and-jackswastedlife).

Comment: I edited the answer. I hope this fixed your problem

Comment: That has fixed the errors, but the choices for each question are the same, whereas the actual choice for each question should be different. If that makes sense?
So for question 1 the choices should be yes, no, maybe. But for question 2 the choices are Good,Bad, Average?

Comment: Yes, you need to replace `'question_id': 1` with the actual question id that you need for that particular answer formset